# oracle database: select between certain time of the day

Tags: sql, oracle

```
column name    data type
wp_stime         DATE
```

QUERY:

```
select wp_stime from workpaths;
```

OUTPUT:

```
29-FEB-12
29-FEB-12
24-FEB-12
24-FEB-12
31-OCT-11
12-DEC-11
12-JAN-11
19-OCT-11
19-OCT-11
11-AUG-11
19-OCT-11
21-NOV-11
28-JUL-11
02-AUG-11
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
01-MAR-12
```

The question is how can I select based on 9AM to 5PM of wp_stime?

QUERY 2 :

```
select to_char(wp_stime, 'HH24:MI:SS') from workpaths;
```

OUTPUT:

```
00:09:20
00:10:17
00:11:26
00:42:50
00:44:32
00:45:35
00:48:47
00:51:45
00:53:01
00:56:43
01:31:39
01:34:01
14:49:30
01:53:32
02:06:37
02:36:54
02:51:12
```

Comment: You are trying to get the time component of a date that does not have a time component

Comment: @cableload i dont think you are right because i can convert to_char and see timestamps. see updated query above

Comment: Ok..i see it now...So you want for any date above, select between 9 and 5?

Comment: oh yeah lol  i guess i can do "where to_char(wp_stime, 'HH24:MI:SS') >= '09:00:00' and
  to_char(wp_stime, 'HH24:MI:SS') <= '17:00:00'"

Comment: does this give you a result with time stamp included ? `select to_timestamp(wp_stime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from workpaths`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from workpaths where to_char(wp_stime,'hh24') between 9 and 16;
```

Should help. Oracle will extract the hour part from your date field as string, and on seeing that you are comparing with numbers would implicitly convert it to number. Thus you can compare between hours. Effectively, this query  gives dates whose time is greater than 9 am and less than 5pm.

**EDIT :**

17 is replaced with 16, so that values till 16:59:59 would be considered.

**EDIT 2 :**

To explicitly perform string to numeric casting :

```
select * from workpaths where to_number(to_char(wp_stime,'hh24')) between 9 and 16;
```

Comment: This will definitely not help, since you are comparing strings, and therefore in lexicographic (alphabetic) order. 10 is less than 9 and less than 17, so 10 will NOT be selected. ALSO:  extract (hour from column) assumes column is a TIMESTAMP data type; the hour extracted that way is **not** NLS dependent. Where do you come up with such ideas? On the other hand, extract (hour from column) **does not work** with DATE data type, as explained in the Oracle documentation.

Comment: @mathguy  : 1. This will work. Because I am comparing between number 9 and number 17, not string '9' and string '17'. Oracle will implicitly try to cast the string that I obtain as number, and in this case, the string will always be numeric. 2. NLS : Thanks for correcting. I was under the impression that this had to do something with NLS, since NLS had given me troubles earlier with date formats. Maybe got jaundiced. 3. As for ideas,due to lack of experience.

Comment: Actually you are right, this WILL work, because Oracle will convert the string to a number, not the other way around... still, relying on implicit conversions is not ideal. You might make it explicit with to_number(to_char(...))  -  you are not losing anything in efficiency, since Oracle does this anyway (AND it has to guess), and it's easier to read and understand exactly what the code does.

Answer (score 3):

trunc(wp_stime) will return the same date, with the time portion truncated down to 00:00:00. Then wp_stime - trunc(wp_stime) will return the "fractional part" (the time portion of wp_stime). This is expressed as a number, in days. You want this fractional part to be between 9 and 17 hours, or 9/24 and 17/24 days.

Here is the query, preceded by test data in the WITH clause. For you, with the table existing already, the complete query is just the last line in my code:

```
 with workpaths(wp_stime) as (
      select to_date('02-MAY-2016 13:30:44', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
      select to_date('15-FEB-2013 17:43:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
      select to_date('21-DEC-2015  2:15:27', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
      select to_date('02-JAN-2016 10:22:09', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
      )
select wp_stime from workpaths where wp_stime - trunc(wp_stime) between 9/24 and 17/24;
```

**Output**:

```
WP_STIME
------------------
02-MAY-16 13:30:44
02-JAN-16 10:22:09
```

Comment: What if we want to filter out by minutes too? Say till 5.30.

Comment: Then we would compare to 17.5/24, or 17/24 +30/(24*60).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from workpaths where to_date(wp_stime, 'hh24') between 9 and 17;
```

Should work.  In this case, you are using date data type instead of a char data type.

Comment: to_date will create a DATE data type. That cannot be compared to numbers like 9 and 17. Did you make a small effort to test your query, for example by using SYSDATE instead of wp_stime? It's really easy. (You will run into other problems as well: to_date requires a STRING parameter, you provide a date, so Oracle will perform some implicit conversions, some of which may fail.)